# Should a WebSocket server respond with error messages

Tags: websocket, server

If I have a WebSocket server, and it determines that the message that was send by the client is invalid for any reason, or the requested action can not be performed. Is it normal for servers to respond with an error message in some form?

To be clear, this is not about connection related errors. But purely a parsing error of the clients data.

Currently the WebSocket server simply ignores the message, and thus the client can not know if the request was processed. (Except for some occasions where the client needs additional information, then redo the request.)